# xUnit - a new AppDomain per test or not?

Tags: unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

From this [post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/06/whats-new-in-xunitnet-16.html) by Brad Wilson, it seem that xUnit runs tests in separate AppDomains.  It's not clear if that's one AppDomain per test or one AppDomain per assembly.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237886/how-can-i-use-a-separate-appdomain-for-each-xunit-net-test-method) states that it's one per assembly.

Could someone provide a definitive answer?

Comment: Very easy to confirm by experiment. I reckon its per run (which might be a batch or a single test depending on the runner and what it's doing) as there would be no good reason to incur the cost that I can think of