# Run unit-tests in separate processes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, azure-devops

We are currently trying to implement some unit-tests for our `net5.0` application where we would like to run each test-case in its own process.
The reason for this is that each test-case will create a `System.Windows.Application` and only one is allowed per `AppDomain`.
Currently we are using `MSTest v2`, but we are open to using other frameworks.

**Does anybody know how this can be achieved?**

I already tried to reuse a single `Application`, but I can't get it to work reliably, and it seems a little `hacky` to me anyhow, because one failed test-case could leave a "damaged" application.
I also tried to find a way to destroy an `Application` to be able to create a new one later on but did not succeed there either.
The only way we found would be to create only on test-case per assembly, but that would be practically unmanageable with many test-cases.

Note:
The `System.Windows.Application` is needed because the tests do create WPF controls and use the `Dispatcher` (as we try to unit-test some GUI-related code-parts). As long as we only run one test-case at a time it does work fine.

Comment: Please, have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237886/how-can-i-use-a-separate-appdomain-for-each-xunit-net-test-method

Comment: @IgorGoyda Thanks for the link, but multiple AppDomains are not supported on `net5.0`. I removed that also from the question...

Comment: @ChristophFink I have hit the same problem, did you ever manage to find a solution?

Comment: @Luk164 No, sorry...