# How to effectively debug and test a Logger class library that logs unhandled exceptions to disk?

Tags: c#, logging

## Issue

How can I debug and test a Logger class library that logs unhandled exceptions to disk?

I have created a Logger class library with a constructor that registers an event handler for unhandled exceptions. The event handler logs the exception details to a log file on disk. I have also created a unit test to initialize the logger and throw an unhandled exception, but I'm having trouble debugging and testing my code.

When I run the unit test and an unhandled exception is thrown, the test fails and breakpoints in my logger class aren't hit.
Apparently this is due to the Testing framework handling exceptions differently.
How can I debug and test my code effectively?

## Code

this is a minimal working example which will work in a console application but not in a xUnit test:

```
// create event handler for logging future exceptions
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
{
    Exception ex = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
    // Log the exception details
    File.Create("Errtest");
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    { }
};
// Act
throw new Exception("Test exception");
```

Comment: As I texted previously, it is not possible without any wrapping handlers which is Domain Event Handler in your case. I'm sorry I can't help you to solve the problem, however this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237886/how-can-i-use-a-separate-appdomain-for-each-xunit-net-test-method) might help you to configure your xUnit domain in right way and subscribe to event handler from xUnit.

I hope you will find the solution and I hope I will get familiar with it as well.

Answer (score 0):

The test fails as you don't handle your exception. It is not possible to test the unhandled exception logging functionality without a try-catch block in your test code (or some other wrapping handlers).

Try the next code:

```
[Fact]
public void UnhandledException_WritesExceptionToLog()
{
    // Arrange
    var logger = new Logger();
    var ex = new Exception("Test exception");

    // Act
    try
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    catch
    {
        // The exception was caught and logged to the file
    }
}
```

After that make sure you hit the logger and it is logged to the disc. You might also extend your test to check it automatically by adding similar assert:

```
// Assert
Assert.True(File.Exists(logger.LogPath.FullName));
var logText = File.ReadAllText(logger.LogPath.FullName);
Assert.Contains("Test exception", logText);
```

As the result, your test should look like:

```
[Fact]
public void UnhandledException_WritesExceptionToLog()
{
    // Arrange
    var logger = new Logger();
    var exMessage = "Test exception";
    var ex = new Exception(exMessage);

    // Act
    try
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    catch
    {
        // The exception was caught and logged to the file
    }

    // Assert
    Assert.True(File.Exists(logger.LogPath.FullName));
    var logText = File.ReadAllText(logger.LogPath.FullName);
    Assert.Contains(exMessage, logText);
}
```

**Note**: *logger.LogPath.FullName* is accessible only if you set your *LogPath* property/field as *public* one. If not, you obviously should hardcode your *filePath* for testing purposes OR add the accessor to your logger class.

Comment: The thing is, that the logger should log unhandled exceptions and not handled exceptions

Comment: @julianbechtold unfortunatelly, the CLR terminates the current process and prevents the code execution in case of exception is thrown, including the testing methods

Comment: This is incorrect. I will post a minimal working excample in case you dont believe me.

Comment: @julianbechtold I didnt tell I don't believe you. Please, share the example and I will take my words back